# Sqlserver temporary table name from variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting error when i run this query

```
declare @query varchar(700)
declare @tbl varchar(50)='#mytbl'
set @query='select check_details.id, check_details.point_no into '+ @tbl+ ' FROM check_details'
exec @query
```

What i am missing.

My error is 
Database 'select check_details' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

If i run

```
select check_details.id, check_details.point_no into #mytbl FROM check_details
```

This works perfectly

Comment: Msg 911, Level 16, State 4, Line 6
Database 'select check_details' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
exec sp_executesql @query
```

or

```
exec (@query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parentheses:

```
exec(@query)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot , I got solution by you guys.